# Data extraction using Regular expressions

Tags: regex, excel, powershell

Hi I have a file of the format

```
 [stuff not needed]Type:A1[stuff not needed]
 [stuff not needed]Name:B1[stuff not needed]
 Row:Sampletext
 Row:Sampletext
 [stuff not needed]Type:A2[stuff not needed]
 [stuff not needed]Name:B2[stuff not needed]
 Row:Sampletext2
 Row:Sampletext2
 Row:Sampletext2
```

I am using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to extract the data.

I am using something like `Regex1|Regex2|Regex3` ,and saving the output to a file.

The output comes in the format:

```
A1
B1
Sampletext
Sampletext
A2
B2
Sampletext2
Sampletext2
Sampletext2
```

I want it in the format

```
A1 B1 Sampletext
A1 B1 Sampletext
A2 B2 Sampletext2
A2 B2 Sampletext2
A2 B2 Sampletext2
```

I am new to PowerShell, is there any way I can do this ?

This is the exact code the I have:

```
$input_path = ‘idx.txt’
$output_file = ‘output.txt’
$regex = ‘Type:\s([A-Za-z]*)|Name:\s\s([A-Za-z]*)|[A-Za-z][a-z0-9A-Z_]*(?:\s*[0-6]\s*[0-4]\s\s[\s\d]\d\s*0)’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

The data is too big to be posted here ,but ill just create a sample data set.But the regular expressions are working ,maybe crude but its capturing the data required .
for the sake of the example ,we can have Type:([A-Za-z]*)|Name:([A-Za-z]*)|Row:([A-Za-z]*) as the regular expressions

Comment: @wOxxOm I added the edits

Comment: further edited ,please check now if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check every line if it has `type` or `name` and set the corresponding variables only, but if it has `row` output the type and name variables along with the current row contents.

```
$allmatches = Select-String '(Type|Name|Row):\s*(\w*)' $input_path -allmatches
$output = foreach ($m in $allmatches) {
    $data = $m.Matches.Groups[2].Value
    switch ($m.Matches.Groups[1].Value) {
        'Type' { $type = $data; break }
        'Name' { $name = $data; break }
        'Row'  { "$type $name $data" }
    }
}
$output | Set-Content $output_path -Encoding UTF8
```

Notes:

- We use a faster `foreach` *expression* instead of slower pipelining via foreach with a scriptblock.
- `\w` in regex means any word character including a-zA-Z0-9 and _ and [some more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter)
- Regex-matching and string comparison are case-**in**sensitive in PowerShell by default

Comment: Thanks so much ,i used the code , The argument of select-string are the three regex with pipes in between right ?

Comment: but i am getting the following error "Cannot index into a null array.
At line:6 char:23
+     $data = $m.Groups[ <<<< 2].Value
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (2:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray"

Comment: any idea what might be causing this